# Add suffix to variable

Tags: variables, suffix

I want to add the string MN to the year 2021, assigned to Targetyear.

```
%put &Targetyear1_MN;
```

This one works:

%put MN_&Targetyear1;

How can I add the MN at then end?

Thanks.

Kind regards,
Ben

Comment: &Targetyear1 _MN with a space works,  is there a way to build this without a space?

Comment: I found it out: Use a ., like this: %put &Targetyear1._MN;